# AWS App Runner start command with quoted whitespaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, escaping, amazon-app-runner

I'm creating an [AppRunner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/) service from a private ECR image with a Start command:

```
--before 'echo $MYVAR > /tmp/log.txt'
```

Which should be passed as is into my container entrypoint.

However, in App Runner application logs I get an error:

```
Couldn't find match for argument PARSE ERROR: Argument: $MYVAR
```

If I run the image using just Docker the whole  `'echo $MYVAR > /tmp/log.txt'` is interpreted as one argument to `--before`.

But in the App Runner two arguments are passed to the entrypoint:

- `--before` with `'echo` value
- `$MYVAR > /tmp/log.txt'`

Second argument cases a parsing error in the entrypoint since it's invalid.

I have tried various ways of specifying an entrypoint but they all fail:

```
--before "echo $MYVAR > /tmp/log.txt"
--before \'echo $MYVAR > /tmp/log.txt\'
```

Is there any way I can pass `'echo $MYVAR > /tmp/log.txt'` ass one argument to `--before` in App Runner start command?